# How to remove sorting of specific rows of gridview in asp. Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have one Gridview with data. I have already applied sorting and filtering option to Gridview. But i don't want to sort and filter my last 2 rows of Gridview. Please suggest me what can i do for it? . Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net gridview one property is provided by .net. Which is called as custom sorting.
By custom sorting method. you have to slice bottom two rows and sort the 1st half of data and append 2nd half sliced row. Return as a set.

For reference [Custom sorting in grid view by MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hwf94875(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Thanks @Kiran Potawale, English is not my first language, If any grammatical mistake please ignore or edit into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set the SortExpression on those columns you don't want to Sort on.